# Force Windows 8 to use touchpad as single-button?

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey, touchpad

I have an Asus V551L laptop with Windows 8.  It's a great, medium-grade laptop, but the touchpad is driving me nuts.  I'm constantly accidentally triggering right-clicks, since the touchpad doesn't hae physical buttons, just a divided area at the bottom of the pad that is for left and right clicks.

What I would love to do is force Windows to treat the touchpad like a single-button mouse, so that it would register both areas of the touchpad as left clicks, possibly treating a ctrl-click as a right click, similar to the way OSX typically does.

I've messed around with Auto-Hotkey, to try to get this mapping down, but it doesn't seem to work.  I can remap a right-click to send a left-click instead, but if I try to setup the ctrl-click = right-click mapping, it appears to end up catching the original click and ctrl button, then sending a right-click, which is then intercepted by the original handler and converted back into a left-click...

I've figured out how to get a Ctrl-Right-Click to trigger a left-click, which kind of works, although I have to remember to hold down Ctrl, which is kind of the opposite of what I want.

```
^RButton::LButton
```

It seems like I need to somehow detect the Ctrl button being down, and unbind the RButton::LButton mapping, then restore it when the Ctrl button is released, but I haven't seen a good example of how to do this.  It feels like this is something that other people must have run into...

Comment: As a start, try putting a `$` before the `^RButton::LButton` line; that makes it so it isn't triggered by other hotkeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to echristopherson, you got me on the right track.

I've discovered that the following script gets me what I want:

```
^RButton::RButton
RButton::LButton
```

The order is important here... The ctrl-right->right mapping definition has to be before the mapping for right->left.  It seems that (at least on my machine, with the version of Autohotkey I have, 1.0.48.05) that this works.

It's possible that the second line should be:

```
$RButton::LButton
```

to prevent the first mapping from triggering the second, but it works as in on my machine.